# Why can't a data class conform to an interface if its property conforms to the interface's property's interface?

Tags: android, kotlin, interface

```
interface BarInterface {
    val bar: Int
}

interface FooBarInterface {
    var foo: BarInterface
}

data class Bar(override val bar: Int): BarInterface {}

data class FooBar(override val foo: Bar): FooBarInterface {}
```

fails with

```
Var-property public open val foo: Bar defined in FooBar cannot be \
overridden by val-property public abstract var foo: \
BarInterface defined in FooBarInterface
Type of 'foo' doesn't match the type of the overridden var-property \
'public abstract var foo: BarInterface defined in FooBarInterface'
```

How can I work around this, while keeping the interface / data class approach?

Comment: Use `override var` instead of `override val`, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few things, I think my best approach at the moment is

```
interface BarInterface {
    val bar: Int
}

interface FooBarInterface {
    var _foo: BarInterface
    val foo get() = _foo
}

data class Bar(override val bar: Int): BarInterface {}

data class FooBar(override val foo: Bar): FooBarInterface {
    override var _foo: BarInterface = foo
}
```

that allows me to do

```
val bar = Bar(bar = 1)
val fooBar = FooBar(foo = bar)
val barInterface: BarInterface = bar
val fooBarInterface: FooBarInterface = fooBar

print(fooBar.foo.bar)
print(fooBarInterface.foo.bar)
```

which is not great but works.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a `var`, the following code should be legal:

```
class Bar2(override val bar: Int): BarInterface {}

val fooBar: FooBarInterface = FooBar(Bar(0))
fooBar.bar = Bar2(0)
```

But then you set `fooBar.bar` to a `Bar2` and it only allows a `Bar` (even if you change to `data class FooBar(override var foo: Bar)`).

With `val bar` in `FooBarInterface` it would work.